# RecyclerView load after doing action and not as the fragment loads

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I've been searching in google for some time now for a solution to my problem but I can't find any.
My `RecyclerView` getItemCount() returns 0 and only after I switch between few fragments and get back to the fragment I use the `RecyclerView` in the adapter loads and return the real item number.
I did put logger inside my getList function and even tho the items are pushed inside my array the command array. size return 0... I really can't find solution here.

this is some code to work with
BTW -> first time i use FireBaseDataBase when i used SQLite i did not had problem with recylcer view.
if u need more code lemme know
many thanks! people help me here :)
fragment code:

```
package com.seanCo.DeliveryApp.fragments

import android.app.Activity
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.Context
import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Parcel
import android.os.Parcelable
import android.renderscript.Sampler
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.View.inflate
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageButton
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AlertDialogLayout
import androidx.core.content.res.ColorStateListInflaterCompat.inflate
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener
import com.seanCo.DeliveryApp.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.adding_delivery.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.adding_delivery.view.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_active_delivery.*
import java.sql.Date
import java.sql.Time
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.LocalTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

class activeDeliveryFragment(db : DatabaseReference) : Fragment() {

    val tempDB = db
    var deliveryID = 0
    var tempList : MutableList<deliveryInfo> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val cView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_active_delivery, container, false)
        val tView= activity

        findId()
        val toolbarTitle = tView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.toolbar_title)
        val toolbar = tView?.findViewById<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
        val text = toolbarTitle?.setText("משלוחים פעילים")

        val delivery = deliveryInfo()
        val addButton = cView.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.plus_button)
        addButton.setOnClickListener{

            val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
            val dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.adding_delivery, null)
            dialog.setView(dialogView)
            val dialogData = dialog.show()

            dialogView.dialog_pos.setOnClickListener{
                dialogData.dismiss()
                delivery.address = dialogData.et_address.text.toString()
                val timer = setTime((dialogData.et_timer.text.toString()).toInt())
                delivery.timer = timer
                deliveryID++
                val array : Array<Any> = arrayOf(delivery.address, delivery.timer)
                Log.i("tag", delivery.timer.toString())
                tempDB.child("activeDeliveryies/$deliveryID").child("addess").setValue(delivery.address)


            }

            dialogView.dialog_neg.setOnClickListener{
                dialogData.dismiss()
            }

        }


        return cView
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        refreshList()
        return super.onResume()
    }


    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        rv_activeDelivery.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        return super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    }


    fun refreshList(){
        getList()
        rv_activeDelivery.adapter = rvAdapater(requireContext(), this, tempList)
    }

    fun getList(){
        tempDB.child("activeDeliveryies").addValueEventListener( object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            }

            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                for(id in snapshot.children){
                    val temp = id.key.toString().toInt()
                    if(temp > tempList.size) {
                        for (address in snapshot.child(id.key.toString()).children) {
                            val infoList = deliveryInfo()
                            infoList.address = address.getValue().toString()
                            tempList.add(infoList)
                            Log.i("first", address.getValue().toString())

                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        })

    }

    fun setTime(timer : Int) : Int{
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
           var getTime = LocalDateTime.now()
           var hours = getTime.hour
           var minutes = getTime.minute + timer
           if(minutes >= 60){
               minutes -= 60
               hours += 1
           }
             val newTime = "$hours$minutes"
           return newTime.toInt()
        } else {

           var date = java.util.Date()
           val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm")
           val answer: String = formatter.format(date)
           return 0
        }

    }

    fun findId(){
        tempDB.child("activeDeliveryies").addValueEventListener( object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                for(id in snapshot.children){
                    deliveryID = (id.key.toString()).toInt()

                }
            }
        })
    }

    class rvAdapater(val context : Context,val activeDelivery : activeDeliveryFragment,val list : MutableList<deliveryInfo>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<rvAdapater.ViewHolder>(){
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
            return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(activeDelivery.context).inflate(R.layout.rv_child_activedelivery, parent, false))
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            Log.i("tag", list.size.toString())
            return list.size
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: rvAdapater.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            holder.deliveryAddress.text = list[position].address
        }

        class ViewHolder(v : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v){

            val deliveryAddress : TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.tv_address)

        }
    }


}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
    fun refreshList(){
        getList()
        rv_activeDelivery.adapter?.registerAdapterDataObserver(object : RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
            override fun onChanged() {
                super.onChanged()
                Log.d("frag", "numberOfItems: " + rv_activeDelivery.adapter?.getItemCount())
            }
        })
        rv_activeDelivery.adapter = rvAdapater(requireContext(), this, tempList)
        (rv_activeDelivery.adapter as rvAdapater).notifyDataSetChanged()

    }
```

**UPDATE: Found solution:**
i just changed the order of the commands inside refreshList method

```
  fun refreshList(){
        val con = this
        tempDB.child("activeDeliveryies").addValueEventListener( object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            }

            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                Log.i("datachanged", "data")
                for(id in snapshot.children){
                    val temp = id.key.toString().toInt()
                    if(temp > tempList.size) {
                        for (address in snapshot.child(id.key.toString()).children) {
                            val infoList = deliveryInfo()
                            infoList.address = address.getValue().toString()
                            tempList.add(infoList)

                        }
                    }
                }
                rv_activeDelivery.adapter = rvAdapater(requireContext(), con, tempList)
                val temp = (rv_activeDelivery.adapter as rvAdapater)
                
            }
        })


    }
```

Comment: your refreshList() method is only called after everything has finished loading (onResume()).   You can consider refactoring your codes to call refreshList() in the onCreate() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is loaded from Firebase Realtime Database asynchronously, meaning that you cannot simply call `getItemCount()` directly on your adapter object, as it will always be **zero**. So in order to get the total number of items, you need to register an observer like in the following lines of code:

```
rv_activeDelivery.adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(object : AdapterDataObserver() {
    override fun onChanged() {
        super.onChanged()
        Log.d("TAG", "numberOfItems: " + rv_activeDelivery.adapter.getItemCount())
    }
})
```

And for Java users:

```
adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged() {
        super.onChanged();
        Log.d("TAG", "numberOfItems: " + adapter.getItemCount());
    }
});
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer i appreciate it alot.
I am not so familiar with dataObserver so i really dont know where to put the code u sent me and didnt understand how exactly it does solve me problem.
when i load my program with the code i shared here my recyclerList is showing up only after i switch between fragments. please help me find solution i wont have to do it to see the list.

Comment: You should use this code in the exact place you need to display the number of items. But don't forget, the data is loaded asynchronously, so it takes some time until the number of items is available.

Comment: i dont need to dislay the number of items. i need to get the function "getItemCount" to return the real number of items i got in the list the second my fragment is loaded and not after some time

Comment: please dont leave me here alone with my problem xD i know im hard

Comment: *I don't need to display the number of items. I need to get the function "getItemCount" to return the real number of items*, yes that's the solution you should go ahead with.

Comment: Okay i added this piece of code in my refreshList function(i updated my post with teh code) and still it didnt solve my problem i still need to switch fragment and go back to activeDelivery fragement inorder to see the list
something else i found out when i click the dialog box to add new Delivery and send it into "Firebase database" the recyclerView list is disappear until i switch fragments again.

Comment: solved the problem i add an edit with the solution if u wanna take look at it